# Accessing localhost website on LAN from VMware

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, vmware-workstation

Systems:
Windows Server 2008 R2
IIS 7.5
VMWare 10

i wanted to access the website hosted from other LAN machines. 
Inside the machine there is a VMware 10 running windows server 2008 r2 and iis 7.5.

i set a bridged connection for the VM and using a static ip xxx.xxx.x.198 in windows server
I added a binding to my website (:122).
I added inbound and outbound rules in the firewall settings.

However, i managed to access the webpage from the host machine (windows 8) outside of the VM. 
But i can't access the webpage from another machine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've checked the firewall machines on both the guest and the host?

Comment: anything i can configure in the host and the guest firewall setting? All i know was setting rules for inbound and outbound. millions thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try disabling the firewalls briefly to check whether that is indeed the problem?